# Refresh Iframe on last viewed page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Im working on a basic site editor. I view my editable webpage from a iframe and when I make changes the iframe reloads back to the index page of the iframe. How can I reload the current page and not get redirected back to the index page?

Im using jquery to reload the iframe using .click and $.ajax success.

```
$("#mainFrame")[0].src = $("#mainFrame")[0].src;
```

Comment: What is the code you currently trigger the reload with? Technically this should be possible with javascript but I assume you already use javascript for the reload so you should show how you do that right now.

Comment: Please see my updates..

Comment: For what do you need the ajax request when you do a reload? Is that to post the page-update and then you reload? And if that is the same irframe, why do you use different selectors?

Comment: You're right, sorry I coppied the wrong code. Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this works....

```
$("#myID")[0].src = $('#myID').contents().get(0).location.href;
```